How to get tables and calculated field that belong to a table?
I am trying to get a list of all the tables, the fields in it and the logic if it is a calculated field in an excel sheet in this format -

table name | fields | Logic

I have tried Tableau server Client and Metadata API but I haven't found anyway to do it.
I know that I can download Workbook, but I cannot find how to get required data from that as well.
I am stuck here for a long time, please help.
Any method involving programming is fine, just not any manual steps.
Thank You!

Hi, I don't quite understand. Where is the worksheet located? Like, are you seeing it online or on your computer? And do you need a list of table names and a list of calculated field names, or do you need all the data that the worksheet is built from?

The worksheet is on my tableau server.
And I am told to do 2 things- 1. Get all the tables on server and their fields and logic if it's calculated field.
2. Get Worksheets along with the tables used for it.
Now for 2nd part I think I have to get Tables being used by datasource of the sheet.

From the worksheet menu, select Describe Sheet to see text describing how the worksheet is configured.
You can also select a field in the data pane, and select Describe to see how the field is defined.
Unfortunately, there is no corresponding Describe command for Tableau data sources
--
Another approach that might help is to use the Document API, so you can write a Python script to extract information from the Tableau workbook (TWB file) A TWB file is a text XML file - so in the worst case, you can parse the XML yourself. But I'd want a good reason to go to that effort.
